# Windows 7 pc freezes for an indeterminate amount of time after unlocking

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, troubleshooting, display

Not sure if this type of question is appropriate for this forum, but I've tried everything I can think of to solve this problem aside from format/reinstall.

I recently got a new work PC (Dell optiplex 755) with windows 7 professional x64. Standard developer software installed for .net development: VS2008, VS2005, SQL management studio, office 2007, etc.

Recently I've been having this weird problem where after I lock my pc, when I try to unlock it, the screen will be black for awhile after unlocking. I can ctl+alt+del and put my password in but then it just goes black. The amount of time on the black screen seems to be related to the amount of time I am away from my PC. If only away a few minutes, it'll take about a minute to get to the desktop. If away for an hour, could take up to 15 minutes. If I lock it and go home for the night, I have to restart my PC in the morning (I've let it sit for an hour after a night of being locked and nothing happened). It doesn't do it every time but definitely the majority of the time.

One weird thing I've seen is that if I remote into my machine before trying to log back in it does not do it. I uninstalled all software back to the point when I remember it started happening and it still does it. I was using this PC for a few weeks without this problem happening at all.

Anyone know what my next troubleshooting steps could be? My IT department tried to fix it by moving my old profile to another disk and having me log in, effectively recreating a profile from scratch but that didn't solve it.

As I said above if this isn't the right forum for these types of questions please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have any desktop background image set, change to photo.
Maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

When the screen is black, try doing another Ctrl-Alt-Del; if that responds, select Task Manager and see what has high CPU or Disk read/writes. Also check the event logs (eventvwr.msc) and see if there are warnings/errors coinciding with your login times.

Answer (score 0):

1. I have a set desktop background.
2. When the screen is black, nothing happens, nothing responds at all, I just have to wait until it's finished doing whatever it's doing.

One workaround I finally found is this: instead of just logging back in as myself, I click "log in as a different user". What happens then is the screen will blink briefly, and then it will allow me to log in as myself (effectively unlocking my PC). Sometimes my windows will be on the main monitor instead of the second one (I run a dual monitor setup).

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue - it was something to do with Windows Aero. Once I disabled the transparency/effects/etc I haven't had the problem since. When using Aero a way to get around it was to click "switch user" then log in as myself. This would reset all my windows on one screen and cause some weird graphical issues on some windows but at least I could log in quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Override your registry keys with the ones below:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\General\AutoRecover]
"AutoRecover Always Enabled"=dword:00000000
"AutoRecover Enabled"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why this would fix the issue the OP has ?